# How to remove "public" tab inside GUD watch window

Tags: emacs

When debugging C++, how do I get rid of this annoying public field tab, if not how do I make it expand automatically?

[image]

Comment: Side question: what's the red bullet next to `return`?

Comment: @fniessen that is a break point.